# Buildozer (kivy app): Requirements (SSL, cryptography): unknown url type

Tags: android, python, ssl, cryptography, buildozer

I need your help. Thank you in advance.

I have built a kivy app which works on my pc and also worked on my android device before.

My python app needs an SSL connection and the lib 'requests', so I added in the .spec-file some requirements (which are needed for python2 as I read in other forum entry).

**The source of my problems is that my error log said the Android App could not establish a connection through SSL because the module was not available.** So I added the requirements as recommended here: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/868

This was the error-log on my Android-Smartphone before I added some requirements (cryptography, pyopenssl, ...)
**

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /data/data/org.wsdt.instabot/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-07-19_0.txt
[WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 19)
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.1.dev0, git-Unknown, 20170717
[INFO   ] Python: v2.7.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:51:13) 
[GCC 4.8]
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] OSC: using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] GL: Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@84.0 AU@  (CL@)>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 320>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <4096>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] Shader: program: <--From Vertex Shader:
--From Fragment Shader:
Link was successful.>
[INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[WARNING] Base: Unknown <android> provider
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[INFO   ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
[ERROR  ] Base: Failed to import "android" module. Could not remove android presplash.
[INFO   ] Base: Leaving application in progress...
[WARNING] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 184, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 826, in run
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 660, in mainloop
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 405, in _mainloop
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 340, in idle
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 325, in dispatch_input
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 231, in post_dispatch_input
[WARNING] stderr:   File "_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7163)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1189, in on_motion
[WARNING] stderr:   File "_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7163)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1205, in on_touch_down
[WARNING] stderr:   File "_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7163)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
[WARNING] stderr:   File "_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7163)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
[WARNING] stderr:   File "_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7122)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:12353)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:11951)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 158, in auth
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 71, in start_bot
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/app/src/instabot.py", line 203, in __init__
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/app/src/instabot.py", line 258, in login
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/instabot/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
[WARNING] stderr: requests.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

**

Here my .spec-File for buildozer:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Instabot

# (str) Package name
package.name = instabot

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.wsdt

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.23

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy,python2,hostpython2,kivy==master,requests,pyopenssl,cryptography,pyasn1,ndg_httpsclient
# right (but requests lib is pulling the version 2): hostpython3,python3crystax

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

If the error log above and my way to solve it (adding requirements) is correct, then I would be very grateful if you could go through the following log (from buildozer).

Here is the error-log. I am sitting for 5 days in a row now and at this point I have no idea how to solve this. I tried so many things and solved so many errors, but this one...

Log-Link:
https://pastebin.com/9Fx4Tuyi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by adding openssl to the requirements in the spec file, do a clean, and rebuild.

```
buildozer android clean
```

then

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```